# what is the meaning of ${$key} in the code below?

Tags: php

I just need to know what is the meaning of `${$key}` in the code. I already searched google but didn't find answers for this code. So please help me understand it ?

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);

    if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
        $missing[] = $key;
        ${$key} = '';
    } elseif (in_array($key, $expected)) {
        ${$key} = $temp;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can read more about variable variables on this manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: See the point about `$$` in the duplicate and this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33880044

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say, we have given code:

```
<?php
$a = 'Hello'; 
$key = 'a'; 

echo ${$key}; 
?>
```

will print:

```
Hello
```

What you are doing here is referring to the value which name is stored in another variable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `${}` is a way to create **dynamic variables**, example:

```
${'a' . 'b'} = 'hello world!';
echo $ab; // hello world!
```

Read more at [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).